# Foreign Key Constraint Fail in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create log entries which has foreign keys of guest_id and department_to_visit

SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `logs`;
CREATE TABLE `logs`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `guest_id_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_time_in` datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `date_time_out` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `purpose` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `department_to_visit` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guest_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_logs_guests1_idx`(`guest_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_logs_dept1_idx`(`department_to_visit`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_dept1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_to_visit`) REFERENCES `dept` (`dept_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_guests1` FOREIGN KEY (`guest_id`) REFERENCES `guests` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Logs Model

```
class Logs extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'logs';
    public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Guest','guest_id','id');
    }
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department','department_to_visit','dept_id');
    }
```

I keep receiving the error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`guest_log`.`logs`, CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_dept1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_to_visit`) REFERENCES `dept` (`dept_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `logs` (`guest_id`, `guest_id_number`, `purpose`, `department_to_visit`, `date_time_in`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4, 2, 2, 1, 2018-12-23 12:53:22, 2018-12-23 12:53:22, 2018-12-23 12:53:22))

whenever I try to create new log record using

LogController

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'guest_id'=>'required',
            'guest_id_number'=>'required',
            'purpose'=>'required',
            'department_to_visit']);
        $logs = new Logs();
        $guest = Guest::findOrFail($request->guest_id);
        $logs->guest_id = $guest->id;
        $logs->guest_id_number = $request->guest_id_number;
        $logs->purpose = $request->purpose;
        echo $request->department_to_visit;
        $department= Department::findOrFail($request->department_to_visit);
//        echo '<pre>',var_dump($department),'</pre>';
        $logs->department_to_visit =$department->dept_id;
        $logs->date_time_in = Carbon::now();
        $logs->save();
//        return redirect(route('home'));
    }
```

using this method

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        {!! BootForm::inline(['route'=>['logs.store'],'method'=>'POST']) !!}

        {!! BootForm::select('guest_id', 'Guest Name',\App\Guest::pluck('last_name','id'),null, [])!!}


        {!! BootForm::tel('guest_id_number','ID Number',null, ['required']) !!}
        {!! BootForm::select('department_to_visit','Department to Visit', App\Department::pluck('dept_code','dept_id'),null,[]) !!}
        {!! BootForm::text('purpose',null,null,['required']) !!}

        {!! BootForm::submit('Save') !!}

        {!! BootForm::close() !!}


    </div>
```

I used to receive errors on guest_id but resolved it. I thought it won't be different with guest_id but department_to_visit continues to receive errors. Please help me out in solving and understanding the cause of the problem

Comment: try to change
`App\Department::pluck('dept_code','dept_id')`
to
`App\Department::pluck('dept_id', 'dept_code')`

Comment: @ЕвгенийОдинец error still persists

Answer (score 0):

Puzzling indeed, because the code looks like it retrieves the relevant primary keys immediately before it tries to use them in the insert, so you'd expect these things to work out.

One of the following queries must produce no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM guests WHERE id = 4

SELECT * FROM dept WHERE dept_id = 1 --is the PK id, or dept_id?
```

Resolve this by providing an ID that exists in the table. Double check that your foreign keys reference the correct remote primary keys (i note that guests table PK is called ID but dept table PK seems called dept_id? Is it correct?) and that the column being searched by the findOrFail method is definitely the primary key column. Is there any possible way that findOrFail can find something, the wrong thing, and NOT fail?

Lastly, when you run these in a query tool, make absolutely sure that the database you're querying in debugging this is definitely the same database that your server is connected to.